# How to judge there are same number of rows in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to know how to write a SQL statements to judge the number of rows in table A equals the number of rows in table B?

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get?

Comment: We would be welcome to help you but we are not here to do the job for you. Please provide what you've tried. It can also be good examples to illustrate your need.

Answer (score 2):

Query the following

```
SELECT 1
FROM 
   (SELECT COUNT(1) TOTAL_A FROM A) TABLE_A_COUNT,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) TOTAL_B FROM B) TABLE_B_COUNT
WHERE TABLE_A_COUNT.TOTAL_A = TABLE_B_COUNT.TOTAL_B
```

It will return a row if the count match.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (select count(*) from a) = (select count(*) from b)
begin
    :
end
```